# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "hasta ahora me desayuno"?

Tags: colombia, locuciones

¿De dónde viene la expresión "hasta ahora me desayuno"?

Al menos en Colombia se usa la expresión "hasta ahora me desayuno" queriendo decir que hasta ahora se entera uno de algo.

En el DPD se puede encontrar este significado:

> [desayunar(se)](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=desayunar)
>
> Con el sentido, también figurado y poco usual hoy, de ‘enterarse de algo que ya saben otros hace tiempo’, el complemento va precedido normalmente de la preposición de: «Pues en este momento me desayuno yo de semejante historia» (SchzFerlosio Jarama [Esp. 1956]).

¿Cuál es el origen de la relación entre desayunar y enterarse de algo?

Comment: Nunca he oído usar esa expresión pero se me ocurre que puede venir del hecho que desayunar es lo primero que se hace normalmente al levantarse por la mañana. Antes de eso uno estaba durmiendo y no se podía enterar de nada. Es una idea sin base ninguna.

Comment: La tercera acepción de desayunar es precisamente esa  http://dle.rae.es/?id=CWz7Axz : 3. prnl. **Tener la primera noticia de un suceso o un acontecimiento que se ignoraba.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El uso metafórico de *desayunarse* como "enterarse de algo apenas comenzada la jornada" parece estar bastante extendido en el ámbito hispanohablante. Hay una pregunta anterior (que no logro encontrar) donde se mencionaba que de hecho *desayunarse* era el único uso común y aceptado hasta no hace mucho. Hoy en día el uso pronominal con complemento (*Hasta ahora me desayuno de esto*) [está restringido a esa metáfora](https://cvc.cervantes.es/el_rinconete/anteriores/noviembre_00/16112000_03.htm).

En algunos lugares el complemento va encabezado por la preposición *de*; en otros, por *con*. Alguien quizá sepa si el significado es exactamente el mismo. En Argentina, por ejemplo, se puede usar cualquiera de las dos preposiciones, pero la connotación es diferente en cada caso:

- *Recién me desayuno de esto.* = "Acabo de enterarme de esto y debería haberme enterado antes."
- *Recién me desayuno con esto.* = "Estoy sorprendido porque acabo de enterarme de pronto de esto."

Notablemente existe también [un uso metafórico antiguo que no es pronominal](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=r51TJ4CJ4e4C&pg=PA610&lpg=PA610&dq=%22desayunarse%20con%20una%20noticia%22&source=bl&ots=Ki3INoCtEC&sig=KNYvmSvhlZ_riGX5BsjWBNMrAY4&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwja9IDy8-rWAhXKi5AKHe5jB3UQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22desayunarse%20con%20una%20noticia%22&f=false) sino transitivo:

> [D]esde antiguo se registra un uso del verbo *desayunar* en su forma
>   no pronominal con el significado aproximado de 'informar por la mañana
>   como primera noticia a alguien de algo'. Este es un texto de Fray Luis
>   de Granada: «Porque no conviene desayunar al pueblo común de estos
>   engaños» (*vid.* CORDE). Este uso permanece, ignoro si con fuerza, en
>   algunas zonas de América. He aquí un ejemplo de la Argentina en CREA:
>   «Por la mañana la desayunó la voz de Marta Méscovo». También en
>   América se registran usos actuales del verbo *desayunar* con
>   complemento de régimen (una forma híbrida de *desayunarse con algo* y
>   *desayunar algo*): «El viernes pasado desayunó con dos panes franceses, jamón y mantequilla» (Perú) (*vid.* CREA); «Bello desayunó
>   con la novedad de su candidatura a algunos dirigentes» (la Argentina)
>   (*vid.* CREA).

No hay una fecha clara en la cual el desayuno comenzó a usarse metafóricamente como el enterarse de algo, pero la metáfora en sí no es difícil de aprehender aunque uno no la haya oído antes. Un ejemplo anecdótico de lo sencillo de la asociación es la cantidad de programas informativos matutinos de radio y televisión que existen llamados *Desayuno de noticias* o algo parecido.